# How to create trigger through phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

On my wamp server I have a version of phpMyadmin that allow me to create trigger through the interface.
But on my server from OVH The option is not there, so I try tu update almost everything I can ( mysql, phpmyadmin ) wich now seem to be the same as my local installation. But I stil can't do that operaion.
When I compare both version there is some differences in the table informations_schema but I don't know what to do to fix that problem.
can someone help ?

Answer (score 3):

phpMyAdmin only displays this option if your MySQL server supports triggers (MySQL 5.0.2 and above) and if your user is allowed to create triggers (he needs "TRIGGER" privilege). You can check your privileges by querying "SHOW GRANTS" in the SQL query box in phpMyAdmin. Maybe your provider doesn't want you to use triggers.

Comment: thanks for your answer Alexander, I will go on that direction, I think my MySQL server is not updated correctly. I was looking on the web how to upgrade it on a gentoo release 2 but it seem it's not so easy ..

Answer (score 1):

If your user have rights to create triggers try to use [CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Or use [Devart dbForge Studio](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) - the best tool for mysql

Comment: I can create them manually ... But when I saw it with the interface it's really more easy to maintain and I would like to do the same on my webserver

Comment: you can see the demo online from phpmyadmin with that functionalité. On the top right in the "plus" you can add trigger and event : http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/